# Validar input de tipo imagen en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estamos realizando un sistema web de registro de mascotas y queremos que al momento de registrar la mascota debe de incluir una foto de la mascota, nos gustaría nos ayuden con la validación de esa foto, quiere decir que ese campo debe no debe de estar vació y las extensiones como .jpg, .png

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12">
     <label for="foto-can">Foto de la mascota</label>
     <div class="custom-file">
       <input                          
       type="file"
       class="custom-file-input"
       id="fotoMascotaRegistra"                                                                            
       />
       <label
       class="custom-file-label"
       for="customFileLangHTML"
       data-browse="Elegir archivo"
       >* Seleccionar una foto</label>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para aceptar tipos en el input file puedes usar el atributo accept, y para forzar que ingresen algo el required, por ejemplo:

```
<input type="file" id="fotoMascotaRegistra" class="custom-file-input" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required/>
```

Comment: Me gustaría en javascript

Comment: @JuanCastro no hace falta javascript para hacer la validación, a menos que estés buscando previsualizar la imagen o algo así.

Comment: @the-breaker tiene razón, personalmente también uso js si necesito previsualizar o validar tamaño de la imagen, en otro caso el mismo html resuelve..

Answer (score 3):

Creo que algo así es lo que buscas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Foto de la mascota:</label>
    <input type="file" id="imgMascota" />

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#imgMascota").change(function(){
                let input = $(this);
                let extencion = input.val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
                if( input.val() != "" ){
                    if( extencion != "jpg" && extencion != "png" ){
                        input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
                        alert("imagen no permitida");
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("favor de cargar una imagen");
                }
            });
         });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La respuesta parece funcionar, pero debes agregar mas información para mejorar la calidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias...